# ssrs 2008: Aggregate grouped data only for most recent date, for use in summary header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Aggregate grouped data only for most recent date, for use in summary header

sample data

```
TEAM    NAME       SALES      DATE  
 A      bob          5        Jun 21  
 A      sam          6        jun 21
 B      john         2        jun 21
 A      bob          9        jun 23
 A      sally        4        jun 23
 C      tom          8        jun 23
```

Most recent dates = (9 + 4 + 8)  = 21

So just have a single cell showing "21"

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the total sales for each date, then order by date descending and take the total sales from the first row:

```
Select Top 1 TotalSales
From (
Select Distinct Date, SUM(Sales) as TotalSales
From #Test
Group by Date) as MyTable
Order by Date Desc
```

Comment: I receive the data 'as is' and cannot alter the schema/format of it

Comment: Can you create another dataset, just for the header?  I'm not clear on what your limitation is precisely.  Are you limited to just creating expressions within the RDL?

Comment: Data is supplied as-is from a fixed query. I can only use SSRS itself to manipulate the data

Comment: I haven't tried such a thing, but it may be possible to create a table, group by date, create a subtotal on that group, suppress all detail rows and other columns, sort by date, and use a visibility expression involving an aggregate function on the group totals to show only the total for the most recent date.